# Cannot edit C preprocessor question due to blocked keyword "error" in title

Tags: support, edits, title, content-blocklist

I just tried to edit this question, to remove some redundancy and fix grammar: [#error directive in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323349/error-directive-in-c)

Unfortunately, I cannot submit my edit, because the title contains the word "error" (which I found out by removing words until the error message disappeared):

> [image: Error message 'Title cannot contain "#error directive in C?".']

I understand that this filter is intended to prevent meaningless question titles like "What is the error?", but I believe that "#error" is valid here, and shouldn't be removed.

How can I work around this?

Comment: If there is no warning when you just keep the title as it is, then just do that. The "What is the" is nice, but not so much needed that we need to look for an workaround for the issue.

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately, the error is also triggered when I don't touch the title.

Comment: @Ivar Interesting. So I need to find a way to stretch the title to contain more than 40 chars?

Comment: Yes looks like it. It is currently 34 chars long, so it just needs a few more. For example "What is the use of the #error directive in C?" should be fine.

Comment: @Tom Thank you, that works well!